# Follow up: Simplified Implementation of ArrayList in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, array, vectors

This question is a follow-up to the my earlier code posted [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/136143/simplified-implementation-of-vector-in-c). In the original question, I created a simplified version of C++ `std::vector`/`ArrayList`. I got many good answers and I thought I would like another code review of my improvements to my original code.

**What I changed**

I Incorporated the reviews from @Loki, @Sean, and @Matthieu. I used some of the code from each of them. More specifically, I heavily used initializer lists now, and I changed the constructor, removed wrongly implemented remove functions, added a swap function, added `noexcept`s, removed duplicated/reused code where possible, and a bunch of other changes.

**Goal**

I still have the same goals as the last review

1. My ArrayList class **guarantees** Strong Exception Safety, using the copy and swap idiom
2. The container still works if T passed in is not default constructible
3. Correctness of the implementation of the Rule of Five
4. General correctness and efficiency (i.e: No memory leaks, dangling pointers ... ...)

Hopefully my new and improved code implements the above 4 points better this time around. I would still like to ask that code reviews focus on those 4 aspects, in addition to any other important style choice errors or any other problems that I missed.

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class ArrayList
{
    public:
        ArrayList(int size = 100);
        ArrayList(const ArrayList<T>& other);
        ArrayList(ArrayList&& other)                                noexcept;
        ~ArrayList();

        ArrayList<T>& operator= (const ArrayList<T>& other);
        ArrayList<T>& operator= (ArrayList&& other)                 noexcept;

        void add(T item);
        void remove(int index);
        void swap(ArrayList& other)                                 noexcept;

        friend void swap(ArrayList& A, ArrayList& B)
        {
            A.swap(B);
        }

    private:
        T* arr;
        size_t allocatedSize;
        size_t actualSize;

        void resize();
        ArrayList(const ArrayList& other, int size);
};

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(int size = 100)
    :arr(static_cast<T*>(::operator new(sizeof(T)*size)))
    ,actualSize(0)
    ,allocatedSize(size)
{

}


template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(const ArrayList<T>& other, int size)
    :ArrayList(size)
{
    try
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i<other.actualSize; i++)
            add(other.arr[i]);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        for(std::size_t i = 0; i<other.actualSize; i++)
            other.arr[i].~T();

        ::operator delete;
        throw;
    }
}

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(ArrayList&& other)
    :arr(nullptr)
    ,actualSize(0)
    ,allocatedSize(0)
{
    swap(*this, other);
}

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::~ArrayList()
{
    for(std::size_t i = actualSize - 1; i>=0; i--)
        arr[i].~T();

    ::operator delete(arr);
}

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>& ArrayList<T>::operator =(const ArrayList<T>& other)
{
    ArrayList tmp(other);
    swap(*this, tmp);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>& ArrayList<T>::operator =(ArrayList<T>&& other)
{
    swap(*this, other);
    return *this;
}

template <typename T>
void ArrayList<T>::add(T item)
{
    if(actualSize >= allocatedSize)
        resize();

    new(arr+actualSize) T(std::move(item));
    actualSize++;
}

template <typename T>
void ArrayList<T>::remove(int index)
{
    if(index<0 || index>actualSize - 1)
        throw std::runtime_error("wrong index");

    for(std::size_t i=index; i<actualSize-1; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = std::move(arr[i+1]);
    }

    actualSize--;
    arr[actualSize].~T();
}

template <typename T>
void ArrayList<T>::swap(ArrayList& other)
{
    using std::swap
        swap(allocatedSize, other.allocatedSize);
    swap(actualSize, other.actualSize);
    swap(arr, other.arr);
}

template <typename T>
void ArrayList<T>::resize()
{
    ArrayList tmp(this, allocatedSize*1.5);
    allocatedSize *= 1.5;
    swap(*this, tmp);
}

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(const ArrayList<T>& other)
    :ArrayList(other, other.allocatedSize)
{
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My ArrayList class guarantees Strong Exception Safety, using the copy and swap idiom

Yes.

> The container still works if T passed in is not default constructible

Yes

> Correctness of the implementation of the Rule of Five

Yes

> General correctness and efficiency (i.e: No memory leaks, dangling pointers ... ...)

Couple of minor bugs (see below) but nothing outrages. No leaks or dangling pointers.

#### Fails to compile:

```
template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>::ArrayList(int size = 100)
                                 ^^^^^ not need in definition

        ::operator delete     ;
        throw;           ^^^^^   need to delete something


template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>& ArrayList<T>::operator =(ArrayList<T>&& other)  
                                                             ^^^^^^ missing noexcept

template <typename T>
ArrayList<T>& ArrayList<T>::operator =(const ArrayList<T>&& other)
                                                                   ^^^^^^ missing noexcept


template <typename T>
void ArrayList<T>::swap(ArrayList& other) 
                                           ^^^^^^ missing noexcept

    using std::swap
                   ^^^^ missing ;
```

#### Destruction order

```
catch (...)
{
    for(std::size_t i = 0; i<other.actualSize; i++)
        other.arr[i].~T();

    ::operator delete;
    throw;
}
```

Like the destructor. I would destroy the members in reverse order (so it behaves like the built in array).

#### Bug 1: Does this loop terminate

```
for(std::size_t i = actualSize - 1; i>=0; i--)
    arr[i].~T();
```

Is `i` ever smaller than zero? Since this is a `std::size_t` I expect it to be an unsigned integer that rolls around to a very large value.

There are two techniques I have seed used.

```
for(std::size_t i = actualSize; i > 0; i--)
    arr[i-1].~T();
```

Or

```
for(std::size_t i = 0; i < actualSize; i++)
    arr[actualSize - 1 - i].~T();
```

#### Bug 2: Failure to increase allocated size

```
ArrayList tmp(this, allocatedSize*1.5);

 // This is subtle.
 // But if the current allocatedSize is 0 or 1
 // then the above will not increase the allocated size.
 // So you need a minimum of 2

     ArrayList tmp(this, std::max(2, allocatedSize * 1.5));
```

#### Flaw 1: Invalid value of allocatedSize

```
ArrayList tmp(this, allocatedSize*1.5);
allocatedSize *= 1.5;   // This is a mistake.
                        // You have not increased the allocated size
                        // of the current object (so this could cause issues)

                        // Luckily you swap it to tmp below which goes
                        // out of scope and is thus destroyed so it is
                        // benign in this context.

                        // The current objects size and allocatedSize
                        // will change with the swap() operation below.
swap(*this, tmp);
```

#### Tidyup

I would move the copy constructor from the bottom upto where the other constructors are.